# How can i do a dynamic SelectOneRadio in ADF with CollectionModel binding?

Tags: oracle, foreach, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, selectoneradio

im trying to do a SelectOneRadio that was linked with a binding in ADF.

Mi binding have this structure:

Parent named "Group" (ID, Group, Orden).
Child named "Action" (ID, Action, Desc).

I want one radio group for each "Group" with each "Action".

[image: My Code]

The web don't have error or i cant see it.

And if i can do this, can i get the value of each radio group?

Thanks for all.

Comment: The question is not clear. It would be useful if you add a screen mockup of what you are expecting out of this.

Answer (score 1):

I will first check if the `value` set on af:iterator is returning expected number of values/rows/items. Then I will check if each of those row item has `children` property, and see if that too is type of List (or related types). If you follow these two instructions, you will know why this isn't working.